# is redis has possible to process the ids collection in one query

Tags: redis

Now I am store a list data with article ids, now I am using lrange to get the article id list. then second I want to query the article from redis(I also cached hot article into redis), is there any way to using in query with article id? or get the article like this:

```
for(long id in ids){
   redis.get(id)
}
```

this way may access redis for n times, only one time to get all article may be the best way. like this:

```
redis.get(ids)
```

access only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MGET` to get values for a list of keys it returns null if a key is not found.

For example

MGET article_1 article_2 article_3 article_4  will return 4 articles in the same order

```
Output: Article1, Article2, Article3, Article4
```

For example, if article_3 is missing,  still it will return 4 items but 3rd one would be null.

```
Output: Article1, Article2, null, Article4
```

> MGET key [key ...] Available since 1.0.0.
>
> Time complexity: O(N) where N is the number of keys to retrieve.
>
> Returns the values of all specified keys. For every key that does not
> hold a string value or does not exist, the special value nil is
> returned. Because of this, the operation never fails.

https://redis.io/commands/mget